# PCA by ggplot2 and prcomp

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I'm trying to plot a principal component analysis using prcomp and ggplot2.
Is it possible to graph the average of the groups with the standard error rather than the individual values?
Thank you for the help!!!

Comment: Can you provide example of the plot you desire? You can try box plot to show mean and sd, but PCA are usually plotted with relation to each other.

Comment: That's not an usual representation and I'm not sure it can be done in a visually meaningful way. Maybe would be better to plot the confidence ellipses? Add the options `addEllipses = TRUE` and `ellipse.type = "confidence"` to fviz